# Integration test code coverage for remote application

Tags: automated-tests, code-coverage, jacoco

I have written my tests in such a way that it interacts with the application in test which is deployed somewhere in the cloud (remote). I need to measure the code coverage for these tests.

- I am using maven. And intend on using jacoco + sonar for the code coverage
- What is it that I need to do to add to my POM file to get the coverage
- Do I need to change anything for the JVM  where my application in test is running.

I have tried multiple solutions on the internet but none of them have given me any clear solution. I could be missing the point.

Can someone please guide me through step by step? Help would be much appreciated.